# Android studio3.0.1 emulator: init couldn't find wglgetextension string abb

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming. I tried to use software gles 1.1 in emulated performance when creating a device. I don't have gles 2.0, because my graphic chipset driver don't support OpenGL 2 - I think. It's already updated to the last available version.

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use phone  instead of emulator

Comment: I already started doing so but I need to test in emulator because I feel it's much easier